# Defining a new primitive combinator in Parsec

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec, parser-combinators

## Problem context

I am writing a toy parser (for Scheme), that should be able to distinguish between `-` and `+` as identifiers and as a part of a number (e.g. `+i`, `-2.4`, `+5`). I would like to try-parse anything starting with `+` or `-` as a number, but with a catch: if the parses consumes the sign, but not any characters after the sign, then I would like it to act as if it was wrapped in a `try`, but if any input was consumed after the sign then I'd like it to fail, getting a nice contextual error message and line number/position for the offending character; wrapping the entire parser in a `try` would always backtrack, which is not what I want.

## New combinator: `followedBy`

To this end, I want to create a combinator, which I dubbed `followedBy`¹, that mirrors bind (`>>=`) and takes a parser `m` and a function `k` that returns a parser,

```
followedBy :: ParsecT s u m a -> (a -> ParsecT s u m b) -> ParsecT s u m b
m `followedBy` k = ...
```

and acts as `>>=` except when `m` consumes ok and `k` empty fails, in which case I want the combinator to empty fail. This combinator can then be used as such:

```
(char '+') `followedBy` (\sign -> parseUnsignedNumber sign)
```

to try to parse as a number, fail if it is partially a number but malformed, and empty fail if what follows `+` is not at all like a number.

---

### Low-level implementation

I have adjusted the `parserBind` code from `Text.Parsec.Prim` to do exactly this², but because it uses symbols that are not exported by Parsec I can't compile it. Is there a way to write the same thing using higher-level constructs that are exported by Parsec?

My (uncompilable) implementation for `followedBy` is:

```
import Text.Parsec.Prim

followedBy :: ParsecT s u m a -> (a -> ParsecT s u m b) -> ParsecT s u m b
-- Code adjusted from parserBind in Text.Parsec.Prim. Changed is that mcok.peerr uses eerr instead.
followedBy m k
  = ParsecT $ \s cok cerr eok eerr ->
    let
    -- consumed-okay case for m
    mcok x s' err =
        let
         -- if (k x) consumes, those go straight up
         pcok = cok
         pcerr = cerr

         -- if (k x) doesn't consume input, but is okay,
         -- we still return in the consumed continuation
         peok x s err' = cok x s (mergeError err err')

         -- if (k x) doesn't consume input, but errors,
         -- then we return the empty error (not consuming m or k)
         peerr err' = eerr (mergeError err err')
        in  unParser (k x) s pcok pcerr peok peerr                      

    -- empty-ok case for m
    meok x s err =
        let
        -- in these cases, (k x) can return as empty
        pcok = cok
        peok x s err' = eok x s (mergeError err err')
        pcerr = cerr
        peerr err' = eerr (mergeError err err') 
        in  unParser (k x) s pcok pcerr peok peerr
    -- consumed-error case for m
    mcerr = cerr

    -- empty-error case for m
    meerr = eerr

    in unParser m s mcok mcerr meok meerr
```

---

### Possible alternative

I know that there is also an alternative, namely to `try`-parse `+` as an identifier, along the lines of `char '+' >> parseDelimiter`, and I will take this route if the `followedBy` does not work and another (elegant) solution does not present itself, but I am really curious if `followedBy` can be implemented and, if so, how.

---

*¹) Anyone having a better name for it is welcome to comment.*

*²) I have not been able to test it, so I don't know for sure if my code works correctly.*

Comment: You can get around this with a huge hack - write an exact copy of the `ParsecT` type in your own module, then use `unsafeCoerce` to convert between the two - "guaranteed" to work, as long you never forget to update your code when the library changes the internal representation of the type. The real solution is to get the maintainer to internal an "Internal" module which exports the constructor, but that could be a lot of work. Or just fork the library.

Comment: @user2407038 Thanks for the ideas. I was hoping for a compatible solution, but it doesn't seem like there is any. I don't feel like forking the library, so in practice I'll just use the alternative/work-around.

Comment: Could you explain why `sign >>= \s -> (try (number s) <|> identifier s)` does not give the result you need?

Comment: @sapanoia Separation of concern mostly; I don't want to mix knowledge of identifiers into a function that parses numbers, if it can at all be helped. A similar workaround I mentioned in my post, but here I was looking for an elegant resolution.

Comment: @MicroVirus I see why you do not want to bake them together and, unfortunately, I do not have a solution. In simple cases with a constant prefix, it might be possible to have a function for merging those parsers: `merge [number, identifier]`, but I think it would likely require an Arrows-based parser.